# Not understanding the function of static int in C

Tags: c, function, static, int

I'm trying to understand this piece of code, but I don't know why the amount of a static variable sometimes changes and sometimes not.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int func1 (int x)
{
    extern int a;
    static int y=0;
    printf("%d\n%d\n",a,y);
    a=x+5; y=x+1;
    {int y=10; printf("%d\n",y);}
    return y;
}
int a;
int main()
{
    a=func1(1);
    printf("%d\n",a);
    {
        int a=1;
        printf("%d\n", a);
    }
    a=func1(a);
    printf("%d",a);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
0

0

10

2

1

2

2

10

3
```

At first, when `a = func(1)` is run, `y` is declared as `0` and then changes to `2` and it prints `2`. But when it runs `a = func(a)` when `a` is `2`, I expected that `y` will become `0` through `static int y = 0` but `y` doesn't change. Why it doesn't happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A static object is initialized, conceptually, when it is created.

The lifetime of a static object begins when the program starts executing and continues until execution ends.

So, when the program starts executing, `y` is initialized to 0. After that, its value changes only when it is modified, as with assignment statements. The statement that defines it, `static int y = 0;`, does not modify it after the initialization.

Comment: Does this apply to normal integers as well? will int a = 7 when a is already initialized, change its value?

Comment: @MatinN.: When `int a = 7;` appears inside a function, it has automatic storage duration. A lifetime of an object with storage duration (that is not a variable length array) begins each time its associated block is entered, but the initialization does occur only when program execution reaches the declaration statement. (For a variable length array, a lifetime begins when its declaration is reached.)

Answer (score 1):

Variables declared as `static` inside of a function retain their value through the lifetime of the program, even when the variable name goes out of scope.  The initializer for a `static` variable is *only* applied at program startup.

So when the program starts, `y` is initialized to 0.  Then in the first call to `func` it sets `y` to 2.  This value is retained even after the function exits.  So when `func` is called a second time, `y` is still 2 when the function starts.

Answer (score 0):

static means you have only one shared value of the variable, you can imagine it declared as a global variable keeps its value between multiple function calls.

First times you called the funct1 with x = 1 so y returned as 2.
The next time you called the function func1 with x = 2, the value of y will not be declared again but will use the last value of last call (y=2), and update it with y = x + 1 to be 3.

TLDR;
Read the static declaration of a variable only once (static int y = 0), and do not back to it again, use the last value of it next times.